# Can't reboot netbook with any of the reboot parameters

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, reboot, sony

I have a Sony VPCW218AG netbook that I've dual-booted with Ubuntu 10.10. Unlike the preinstalled Windows 7, Ubuntu will not reboot on this computer. Rebooting from Gnome, using the `reboot` command and SysRq+REISUB all don't work; they end hanging with a blank screen.

I have read that Atom netbooks don't have a keyboard controller and therefore the default reboot method, `kbd`, won't work. I have actually tried all ten `reboot=` parameters listed [here](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/08/04/howto-fix-linux-hangfreeze-during-reboots-and-restarts/); none of them work.

I have also tried disabling ACPI with `noacpi acpi=off` for each one; that didn't help either.

Are there any other things I can try to fix the rebooting problem?

Comment: Why don't you complete your bug report on launchpad with the requested datas? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/ bug/668274

Comment: I'm attaching the files right now.

Comment: All done. Apport tells me to try a mainline/git kernel so I'll try that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various experiments, I've reached a solution for this laptop.

<del>I've installed gentoo, compiling a kernel with `CONFIG_SONY_LAPTOP` and `CONFIG_SONYPI_COMPAT` enabled. With that driver included, setting `reboot=bios` on the kernel command line worked (of course, as `reboot=bios` depends on x86-32, it probably won't work on x86-64 and another solution will be needed). Even though I found this solution in gentoo, it would almost certainly work in Ubuntu too.</del>

After more experimenting, it turns out that the only thing I needed was `reboot=bios`. However, that doesn't work on x86-64, so I'm stuck with x86-32 (that doesn't matter much though; this netbook only has 1GB of RAM).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting bug.  I would try using [Alt-SysRq-T](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=617349) to see what tasks seem to be running, then file a bug based on that.  It would also be interesting to know whether Alt-SysRq-B reboots it or not.

Answer (score 0):

did you also try specifying multiple params?
Avoid using the `kbd` method if the keyboard controller dosen't exists(i actually never encountered this situation, but from old experiences with DOS, accessing invalid controllers may lead to system hangup)..

Are you sure that when the system hangs all other apps are closed?
Did you try looking into `lastlog`?